# Curl single file from gitlab repo during gitlab pipeline run

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a pipeline in repo A that is trying to retrieve a file from another repo (repo B) via `curl`. Both repos are on my self-hosted Gitlab instance.

The pipeline in repo A is simply trying to run this command:

```
curl -H "CI_JOB_TOKEN:$CI_JOB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.myinstance.com/api/v4/projects/111/repository/files/credentials%2Fcredentials%2Etpl/raw?ref=main"
```

When ran in the pipeline I get the error - `{"message":"404 Project Not Found"}`

Running the same command but using a private token works without an issue.

```
curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN:glpat-xxxxxxxx" "https://gitlab.myinstance.com/api/v4/projects/111/repository/files/credentials%2Fcredentials%2Etpl/raw?ref=main"
```

In the repo B I have given repo A CI_JOB_TOKEN access but I still get the same error.

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Ignore that the error code is 404. Everything from 400-499 is a client error, and if you get a code from 500-599 consider it an error with the request, too, albeit it is a server error, but from the perspective of the request it does not matter. This should clarify the error situation: Use tokens that work. Was that your question? /EDIT: See [Allow access to your project with a job token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html#allow-access-to-your-project-with-a-job-token) if there is an endpoint supporting CI_JOB_TOKEN and you need access to a different repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Builtin job tokens only have access to [certain API endpoints](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html). Unfortunately, you cannot access the repository files API with this token.

A workaround is to generate a [project access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html) from the project containing the file you want to download and use that just as you would use a personal access token. Alternatively, you can configure the project to [allow project API access with a job token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html#allow-access-to-your-project-with-a-job-token) from the specific project(s) that need access.

Another workaround that doesn't require a token or project setting changes is to clone the project instead (which the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` *does* let you do by default), but obviously you will have to clone the project with a depth of at least 1 rather than only retrieving the single file needed.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'll maybe just clone the repo instead and work with that.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a known issue:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17511